# malformed array literal when convetring jsonb array of jsonb items to postgres array of jsonb by jsonb_array_elements

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, jsonb, jsonb-array-elements

I have jsonb-array:

```
element_values := '[
  {
    "element_id": "a7993f3d-9256-4354-a147-5b9d18d7812b", 
    "value": true
  }, 
  {
    "element_id": "ceeb364e-bb88-4f41-9c56-9e5f4d0bc1fb", 
    "value": None
  },
  ...
]'::JSONB
```

And I want to convert it into array of jsonb objects: `JSONB[]`

I tried this method:

```
<<elements_n_values_relationship_create>>
DECLARE
    elements_n_values_relationship JSONB[];

BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements(element_values) INTO elements_n_values_relationship;
    ...
END;
```

But I got the following error:

```
 ERROR:  malformed array literal: "{"value": true, "element_id": "a7993f3d-9256-4354-a147-5b9d18d7812b"}"
 DETAIL:  Unexpected array element.
```

Why it does not work?

Comment: Enclose None in double quotes: `"value": "None"`.

Comment: @Benilson problem is not here. Even I have jsonb only with first item, I get error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use *null* in place of *None* to make your statement work

EDIT:
Try this in pgadmin or any SQL client, is is working as expected

```
select   jsonb_array_elements('[{
  "element_id": "a7993f3d-9256-4354-a147-5b9d18d7812b", 
  "value": true
}, 
{
  "element_id": "ceeb364e-bb88-4f41-9c56-9e5f4d0bc1fb", 
  "value": null
}]'::JSONB);
```

| jsonb_array_elements |
| --- |
| "{""value"":"{""value"": true, ""element_id"": ""a7993f3d-9256-4354-a147-5b9d18d7812b""}" |
| { "value": null, "element_id": "ceeb364e-bb88-4f41-9c56-9e5f4d0bc1fb" } |

Comment: Oh, it is miss print. I copied json from python. `Asyncpg` will replace `None` to `null`